# Share my space in Google Drive

Tags: file-upload, google-drive-api

Excuse me, i have a Google Drive account and it has unlimited storage. But i want to share space of my google drive storage to my friend. And i'm use the share to a folder of mine so my friend can edit or upload the files. But when he upload his files, his google drive space is reduced instead. So my question how i can give my space for him but did not reduce his space.

Sorry for my bad english. i'm still learning.

Answer (score 0):

create a folder in your google drive. under folder sharing, select their name/email and set to "can edit".

your friend should log in to their google drive and click on "shared with me" and open the shared folder. they should be able to upload/edit etc as normal, with files being stored under your account, not theirs.

Comment: i did, but his space still reduced. i've been practiced on my other account and that is proven.

Comment: Same issue here. Any other solution for this ?